barren plateaus in hybrid quantum-classical neural network
I have designed a hybrid quantum-classical neural network where the first part is an MLP (multi-layer perceptron) and the second part is a parameterized quantum circuit. The parameters of the quantum circuit are just the output of the MLP, and the weights of the MLP are trainable, while the quantum circuit itself does not have trainable parameters.
More specifically, let $x$ be the model input, the parameters of quantum circuit is $\theta = MLP(x)$, and the output of quantum circuit is given by $y = U(\theta)$, finally we have some loss function $L(y)$.
In this scenario, will the hybrid quantum-classical neural network experience barren plateaus?
PS: We may consider the circuit $U$ in this model to be same with the one studied in the Barren Plateaus paper. Except that the parameters $\theta$ are not trainable, they are simply the output from some classical layer, only weights in the classical layer are trainable.

What is the loss function? And how deep is the circuit?

Generally, we could consider the circuit to be exactly the same one as the Barren Plateaus paper[1]. Except that there are no trainable parameters, all angle values are from previous classical layer.
[1] J. R. McClean, S. Boixo, V. N. Smelyanskiy, R. Babbush, and H. Neven, “Barren plateaus in quantum neural network training landscapes,” Nat Commun, vol. 9, no. 1, p. 4812, Nov. 2018, doi: 10.1038/s41467-018-07090-4.

The basic idea of Barren Plateaus is that if I am computing an expectation value $f(U) = \langle U^\dagger H U\rangle$ that depends on an $n$-qubit unitary $U$, and if I consider sampling this unitary uniformly$^1$ from the unitary group $\text{U}(d)$, then
$$
\text{Var}_{U \sim \text{U}(d)} f(U) = O(2^{-n}). \tag{1}
$$
The underlying assumption with that 2018 paper (and the dozens of others that followed) was that the distribution of parameterized unitaries $U(\theta)$ during training would, on average and with respect to $\theta$, end up looking like$^2$ it was a uniform distribution over $\text{U}(d)$. Showing this is sufficient to demonstrate barren plateaus.
So in your case, you have a distribution $p_X(x)$ over inputs $x$, that induces a distribution of $p_{W|X}(w| x)$ weights $w$ in the MLP (defined implicitly through a loss function), which together induce a distribution $p_{\Theta|XW}(\theta |x,w)$ via $\theta := \theta(x, w)$.
So you should look at your problem and ask, what combination of distributions and functional dependencies would lead to $U(\theta)$ being close to uniformly random? Keeping in mind that it takes a lot of parameters to parameterize $\text{U}(d)$ uniformly, you can ask

Is my distribution of inputs $p_X$ "random enough" to induce a very flat distribution of $U(\theta)$?
Can the induced distribution of weights $p_{W}$ for this choice of $p_X$ lead to a very flat distribution of $U(\theta)$ via the MLP function?
Does the mapping $\theta$ into circuit parameters give you a family of circuits that could explore a large subspace of $\text{U}(d)$?

You can't really say much about the problem without specifying these other pieces in more detail. It can take an entire research paper to make a conclusive claim for a specific choice of $U(\theta)$, even without the MLP you've added on.

$^1$ i.e. with respect to the Haar measure
$^2$ See, e.g., (Holmes, 2021).

Take a quantum circuit $U(\theta)$ and a loss function $L(\theta)$ and define the preprocessor function $MLP(x) =: \theta(x)$. Now your question is whether the minimization of $L$ via $x$ suffers from barren plateaus given that $L(\theta)$ has them. The latter means
$$\mathbb{E}_\theta\left(\left( \nabla_\theta L(\theta)\right)^2 \right) = \mathcal{O}(2^{-n}).$$
with the qubit number $n$. Now the existence of barren plateaus in the weights and biases $w$ requires
$$\mathbb{E}_w\left( \left( \nabla_w L(\theta(x, w))\right)^2 \right) = \mathbb{E}_w \left( \left( \nabla_\theta L(\theta) \cdot \nabla_w \theta(x, w) \right)^2 \right) = \mathcal{O}(2^{-n}).$$
In general, this is not fulfilled, but will be highly dependent on how much knowledge the MLP has over the cost landscape in the space of the $\theta$s. There are two trivial limiting cases that should emphasize the ambiguity of the answer. Case one is $\theta(x,w)=w$ for any $x$. In that case the barren plateau trivially survives. Case two is $\theta(x, w) = \theta_{opt} \, \forall x, w$ with $\theta_{opt}$ being the optimal parameter set. Assuming the minimum of $L$ forms a narrow gorge, the MLP always navigates around the barren plateau making the above variance over $x$ at least $\Omega(1/poly(n))$.
There should be a conversion between the two regimes. It remains to check, how much information about the optimum is necessary to avoid barren plateaus.

Thanks a lot for your answer. My understanding is that Barren Plateaus occur when the circuit is randomly initialized. However, in this case $\theta(x,w)$ is relevant to the input $x$ and should keep some pattern of $x$, thereby avoiding random initialization of the PQC. So the conclusion is that in this "hybrid" model, barren plateaus may not necessarily be a problem. I found my intuition somehow similar to your analysis and would like to know if you agree with me.

BTW, did you mean $\theta(x,w)=w$ in your original answer, so that $\nabla_w \theta(x,w) = 1$ thus $\mathbb{E}_w = \mathcal{O}(2^{-n})$

Thanks, I edited it. Yes, it is a statement about the mean value of the variance of the gradient of your loss function when initializing according to some probability distribution. In your case, this corresponds to the initialization of the weights and biases of the MLP, becuase that determines the parameters $\theta$. If you have a constant initialization, there could be a similar problem, you just drop the expected value $\mathbb{E}$, if $\nabla L^2$ is small, then you will need many samples to resolve the direction of the gradient.
